# How do I add/Invite my friend on Warframe Crossplay?

Tags: pc, ps4, xbox-one, warframe

Crossplay is here! But how do I use it?

I'm on PS4 and my friends are on Xbox and PC. How do I invite them to join me?

Comment: Assuming you've enabled crossplay, To invite friends to your party from another platform the in-game Friends List should be accessed. Upon selecting this option access Friends tab and type the in-game name (PC, Nintendo Switch) or gamertag (Xbox One) of the invited.  Their username should show up on your screen and be available to add. To invite a party, follow the same steps under Party tab. Or this may help... https://www.warframe.com/crossprogression

Comment: [Please don't answer in the comments](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12537/73976)

Comment: I apologise. I'm uncertain, and meant it as helpful information (since I sourced it when scouring another game's forum) until I can find a conclusive answer for the game in question... perhaps my comment serves you as a functional catalyst of sorts?

Comment: @AlbertFD I do appreciate that, it's more along the lines of comments don't show up as answers, and that they do get cleaned up sometimes too. The format of your comment also comes across as an answer too haha.

Comment: Yes, I certainly understand that my comment can be interpreted as being suspiciously like an answer, but I assure you it was meant as a potentially useful stepping-stone toward a more full-bodied, precise response - for what it's worth, as I couldn't find anything online related, comprehensively, to crossplay for Warframe on the PS4, I decided today to install the game myself (seeing that it's free) on my PS4 to try figure it out; but you seem to have done that yourself. Anyway, best of luck, and I may see you somewhere in the Warframe cyberspace! : P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a trick to it! Thankfully it's very simple

In your profile (go to the top left hand corner of the screen where you and your teammate's icons appear, click on your icon and choose "Profile". Then there, at the top of the screen, you'll see your Gamertag, with a suffix.

> Gamertag#111

So, to send an invite to someone, you will need this information first - then you can send an invite. At this stage I don't know if there is a way to send a friend request across platforms, or invite to your clan, etc.

[image: Gamertag for crossplay]